# How do I log out of superuser?

Tags: discussion

I logged in to superuser to uprate a good answer, and I prefer to log out of sites before leaving them for my (and their) security, but I don't see any "Logout" button in the title bar or in any of its dropdown menus, not even in the menu under my avatar top right where I expected it.

My firefox has NoScript enabled with sstatic.net and even ajax.googleapis.com enabled. Does SU really need to runs scripts from  google-analytics, quantserve or scorecardresearch to log me out, or is there something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Upper right corner of the browser window:
[image]